# Apache Camel - all headers are lost except String during routing to ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am setting a List in exchange object's header with other couple of headers and routing it to `ActiveMQ`.

```java
exchange.getOut().setHeader("testList", testList);
exchange.getOut().setHeader("testObject", testObject); 
exchange.getOut().setHeader("header1", "value1");  
exchange.getOut().setHeader("header2", "value2");
```

In the next route when I access the exchange object's header, `"testList"` and `testObject` are not present ! But remaining headers are present (`exchange.getIn().getHeader`).

Can't we send any header ( list or any other object) except String ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Camel documentation:

> For the exchange.in.header, the following rules apply for the header
>   values:
>
> The values must be primitives or their counter objects (such as Integer, Long, Character). The types, String, CharSequence, Date,
>   BigDecimal and BigInteger are all converted to their toString()
>   representation. All other types are dropped.

More information can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/jms
or here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/Message.html

See Camel manual section : **Message format when sending**

Camel will remove headers not allowed types, but you can use **vm** or **seda** components instead of **activemq**. Or you can convert your list into XML or JSON, convert it to a string and send this string 
through JMS.